# How to create a user with lastRefreshTime for testing?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function for delete inactive users

Production

```
export const cleanInactiveAccount = pubsub.schedule("every 24 hours").onRun(async () => {

const usersToDelete: string[] = [];

// This solution is mixed from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users
const listAllUsers = async (nextPageToken: string | undefined) => {
  // List batch of users, 1000 per batch.
  await defaultAuth
      .listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
      .then(async (listUsersResult) => {
        listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
          // Since account created, If user not use their account,
          // Then add to list for delete.
          if (userRecord.metadata.lastRefreshTime == null) {
            usersToDelete.push(userRecord.uid);
          }
        });

        if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
          // List next batch of users.
          await listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
        } else if (usersToDelete.length >= 1000) {
          console.log("usersToDelete hit the limit");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error listing users:", error);
      });
  };

  await listAllUsers(undefined);

  await defaultAuth.deleteUsers(usersToDelete);

  return "Successful";
});
```

Testing

```
test("cleanInactiveAccount", () => {
  await defaultAuth.createUser({
    // I want to do something like this.
    lastRefreshTime: new Date().getTime()
  });
  const wrapped = wrap(functions.cleanInactiveAccount);
  await expect(wrapped(data, context)).resolves.toEqual("Successful");
});
```

The value is generate by server, I can't create user with custom lastRefreshTime, I have no idea how to test it.

Comment: I'll have to come back to this later, but you probably want to look at [`defaultAuth.importUsers(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.userimportrecord.md#userimportrecord_interface) instead. If you create an old entry, it should create a user that doesn't have a refresh time linked to it. To update it with a refresh time, you might need to spin up a temporary firebase client SDK instance connected to the emulator and sign the user in which should set the `lastRefreshTime` to the current time.

Comment: Didn't know I can import user like this, But seems the field `lastRefreshTime ` [has been removed in 29 June, 2020](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#version_8130_-_29_june_2020).